# Hot to get the 200 response code inside the Volley response block

Tags: android-volley

My app uses volley library for networking operation. I want to get the response code (that may be 200 or 401) inside `onResponse(`) method. How can i achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean to achieve response code 200?. You will get it once everything is correct i meant that proper authentication, parameters, request type etc

Comment: what type of request are you using

Answer (score 1):

you can make a custom request and override:

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //do smth
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        //do smth else
    }
    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
}
```

this way you will still receive the same data in your callbacks but special cases typical for the request you can handle within the request itself.